# Qt widget promotion error after reconstruct the folder of code

Tags: qt, widget

Class `DCGraphicsView` is a subclass of QGraphicsView, I put a QGraphicsView Widget on the UI file `framework.ui`. And the I promote that QGraphicsView Widget to `DCGraphicsView`. After `clean`, `qmake` and `rebuild`, everything is OK as expected.

But after I moved those code and ui file into a subfolder named `ui`, and modify the `pro` as well, use the same procedure as previous (`clean`, `qmake` and `rebuild`). An error message displayed when doing `rebuild`.

To figure out what causes this error, I cancel the promotion of `QGraphicsView` Widget, then no error pops out. If I put it back, the same error comes again. Confused.

error message as follows:

```
No rule to make target 'dcgraphicsview.h', needed by 'ui_framework.h'.Stop.
```

Comment: ```DCGraphicsView.cpp```, ```DCGraphicsViw.h``` as well as ```framework.ui``` are still in the same folder after the moving folder operation. Thus in ```ui``` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The "Header File" field in the promote dialog should contain the path of the header file relative to the base directory from which *uic*, Qt User Interface Compiler, is executed, so it should be "ui/dcgraphicsview.h".

You can change the path by double clicking on the path in the "Promoted Widgets" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I got the right solution. In `pro` file, use `UI_DIR` to specify the location of ui files. In unix like system, use `unix:UI_DIR`; and `win32:UI_DIR` for windows.